# What’s the difference between multipart form data and binary file upload in Postman?

Tags: postman

Postman let’s you upload files via `multipart/form-data` or as a binary. What’s the difference between these two?

Answer (score 1):

[`Binary data`](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/requests/#binary-data)

> Binary data allows you to send things which you can not enter in
>   Postman, for example, image, audio, or video files. You can send text
>   files as well.

[`Form-data`](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/requests/#form-data)

> `multipart/form-data` is the default encoding a web form uses to
>   transfer data. This simulates filling a form on a website, and
>   submitting it. The form-data editor lets you set key-value pairs
>   (using the data editor for your data.) It also lets you specify the
>   content type for each part of a multi-part form request individually.
>   You can attach files to a key as well.
>
> When you repeatedly make API calls that require sending these files
>   again and again, Postman persists your file paths for subsequent use.
>   This also helps you run collections that contain requests requiring
>   file upload.
>
> Uploading multiple files each with their own Content-Type is not
>   supported yet.

Good read: [Postman Learning Center](https://learning.getpostman.com)